# How to use sns.catplot to visualize the change of a dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

I have a dataset that changes mean and variance after time, but still is in the same range of y values. I want visualize the change of the data. Here is the plot with the features I'm looking for:
[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to create such a beauty. I tried the `seaborn.catplot()` function but I'm missing the option to visualize the mean and the connections of the individual datapoints.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist_1 = np.random.beta(2.,2.,250)
dist_2 = np.random.beta(3.,4.,250)
data = {"dist 1": dist_1, "dist 2": dist_2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sns.catplot(data=df, s=3.)
plt.show()
```

The result would be something like this:

[image]

Any ideas to add the missing features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a categorical plot you need to create a data frame that contains a categorical column. I made slight modifications to your code with respect to the column names - 
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
dist_1 = np.random.beta(2.,2.,250)
dist_2 = np.random.beta(3.,4.,250)
data = {"dist1": dist_1, "dist2": dist_2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['id'] = df.index
```

I added a column for the index of each row so that I can use it to convert this wide dataframe into a long one.

```
long_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 'dist', 'id', 'cat').reset_index()
long_df.head()
#   id  cat      dist
#0   0    1  0.558567
#1   1    1  0.265868
#2   2    1  0.076470
#3   3    1  0.891855
#4   4    1  0.215208
```

Now I want to use the cat column on the x-axis of the catplot, dist on the y-axis and create a [point plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html#point-plots) for each row in the original dataframe.

```
sns.catplot(x="cat", y="dist", hue='id', kind="point", data=long_df, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

This gives you the following plot -

[image: Catplot]

---

**Bonus**: You can also do the same using a [line plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and add the markers for mean.

```
mean_df = long_df.groupby('cat')['dist'].mean().reset_index()
mean_df
#   cat      dist
#0    1  0.535771
#1    2  0.399939
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
sns.lineplot(x='cat', y='dist', hue='id', data=long_df, legend=False, ax=ax1)
ax1.plot(mean_df['cat'], mean_df['dist'], 'x')
plt.show()
```

Which gives you -

[image: Line plot with mean added]

The 'X' on each category represents the mean. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome! Any idea about the mean feature other than editing with paint? :)

Comment: Sure, I've edited my answer to reflect the requirements